# How to fail on non-empty sections in a GNU ld linker script?

Tags: ld, linker-scripts

I have this in my GNU ld linker script:

```
  .ctors : ALIGN(4) SUBALIGN(4) {
    *(.ctors)
    ASSERT(0, "Constructors (.ctors) are not supported.");
  }
```

In earlier versions of GNU ld (such as 2.24), this triggered the assertion only if the section `.ctors` was nonempty. In newer version, it always triggers the assertion. How do I trigger it only if `.ctors` is non-empty?

Comment: maybe it's better to add a check for non-empty `.ctors` section before triggering the assertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example , the `__ctors_start` variable should be defined prior to being used in the section's definition.

```
.ctors : ALIGN(4) SUBALIGN(4) {
    *(.ctors)
    __ctors_end = .;
    __ctors_size = __ctors_end - __ctors_start;
    __ctors_start = .;
    ASSERT(__ctors_size == 0, "Constructors (.ctors) are not supported.");
}
```

This is an updated version of the linker script that properly defines `__ctors_start` before utilizing it in the section definition

```
.ctors : ALIGN(4) SUBALIGN(4) {
    __ctors_start = .;
    *(.ctors)
    __ctors_end = .;
    __ctors_size = __ctors_end - __ctors_start;
    ASSERT(__ctors_size == 0, "Constructors (.ctors) are not supported.");
}
```

good luck !

Comment: Why are the variables defined in this order? Shouldn't `__ctors_start` be defined much earlier?

Comment: @pts Indeed, linker scripts must be processed in a specific order, and any symbols or variables used within a section must be defined prior to processing that section, If you want I can update my answer again.